# How to understand “add(1)(2)(3)=6”?

Tags: javascript, function, tostring, currying

I am learning curry function in javascript. 
And a question occurs to me.

```
// how to implement the add function in the below.

add(1)(2)(3) = 6;
add(1, 2, 3)(4) = 10;
add(1)(2)(3)(4)(5) = 15;
```

I've known the implemented code

```js
function add() {
var _args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
var _adder = function () {
    _args.push(...arguments);
    return _adder;
};
_adder.toString = function () {
    return _args.reduce(function (a, b) {
        return a + b;
    });
}
return _adder;
}
console.log(add(1)(2)(3)(4)(5))    // function 
console.log(add(1)(2)(3))          // function
console.log(add(1, 2, 3)(4))       // function

console.log(add(1)(2)(3)(4)(5) == 15)  // true 
console.log(add(1)(2)(3) == 6)         // true
console.log(add(1, 2, 3)(4) == 10)     // true

console.log(add(1)(2)(3)(4)(5) === 15)  // false
console.log(add(1)(2)(3) === 6)         // false
console.log(add(1, 2, 3)(4) === 10)     // false
```

I know how the implemented code works.
But I am very curious about the question. 
From my view, " add(1)(2)(3) = 6; " means that after executing the expression "add(1)(2)(3)", it should return a value which is fully equals to Number 6. But from this question and its implement codes, I may have a misunderstanding about the question. SO, what does the question REALLY mean? This question is often asked by the interviewer.

Comment: On my Chrome browser the first three cases return the numbers 15, 6 and 10 and not "function".

Comment: Two more variants: `console.log(typeof add(1)(2)(3)(4)(5))` returns "function" and `console.log(add(1)(2)(3)(4)(5) +0 === 15)` returns "true".

Comment: oh. That's queer indeed. I use chrome too. Its version is 83.

Comment: I just test the code in my safari(version 13.1) and firefox(version 76) browser. In firefox, the first three cases return functions. And in the safari, it returns the number 15, 6 and 10. But when I want to see the type of the "add(1)(2)(3)(4)(5)", the safari just give me "function".

Answer (score 1):

This comes down to the JavaScript operators.

`=` does assignment.

`===` does a normal equality comparison. A function never equals a number.

`==` does troublesome type conversions on the two values, then an equality test. It's usually better to avoid it. In this case, those type conversions can convert your curried function to a string, which might call your `toString` method if its complicated rules make it coerce the first arg to a string, which runs your curried function, and it converts the other argument to a string, and the two strings are equal.

This kind of automatic-conversion-and-hope-for-the-best test is easy to do the wrong thing. Examples:

- `console.log(add(10)(-10) == '')` --> true
- `console.log(add(10)(20) == 30)` --> true
- `console.log(add(10)(20) == ' 30 ')` --> true
- `console.log(add(10)(20) == 036)` --> true
- `console.log(add(10)(20) == ' 036 ')` --> false
- `console.log(add(10)(20) == ' 36 ')` --> false
- `console.log(add(2)(-2) == [])` -> false
- `console.log(0 == [])` --> true

Also see https://stackoverflow.com/a/359509/1682419

Comment: @quan The important point here is `.toString()` is the troublesome method. `console.log` is calling `.toString()` which is converting the integer. Here's a sweet resource on currying https://javascript.info/currying-partials#advanced-curry-implementation

Comment: @djthoms if the code was `console.log(add(1)(2)(3)(4)(5))`, then indeed `console.log` would be calling `.toString()`. But in this case, the code amounts to `console.log(… == 15)` so JavaScript runs the `==` operator before converting _that_ result to a string.

Comment: I know the implement code. And the method of toString and valueOf will be called in order when an Object is forced to convert to the primitive type of String. Thank you after all. I just cannot figure out the actual meaning of the question.

Comment: @quanlili If the interviewer's question is "how to understand this?", I take that to mean "how to predict the result?", "what happens if you make small changes to it", and "when or why would you use this or avoid using this in writing software?" I wouldn't use the self-currying function in JavaScript because its return value interacts with other operations in a hard-to-predict way. When engineering software, we want code that's easy to predict, easy to modify, reliable across browsers.

Comment: It's bad idea to write such code in an actual project. But the interview is the interview.